# i can't figure out how to put json response into html element

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I wrote this bit of code, and the response comes when I make the api call but I can't figure out why it doesn't show up in the html page.

I really don't know what to do at this point because the page loads but the text doesn't show up in the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>IN THE NEWS</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="api.css">
<meta charset="utf-8" lang="eng">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sports section">
        <h1>SPORTS</h1>
        <P class="sport"></P>
    </div>
</body>

</html>


 const NewsAPI = require('newsapi');

 const newsapi = new NewsAPI('API_KEY');

 let sports = document.querySelector(".sport").innerHTML;

newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
category: 'sports',
language: 'en',
country: 'us'
}).then(res =>{
let val = res.articles[0];

sports = val;

})
.catch(rej=>{
console.log(rej);
})
```

this is the information gotten from the api call

```
{
  source: { id: null, name: 'New York Times' },
  author: 'Tariq Panja',
  title: 'Manchester City’s Champions League Ban Is Overturned - The New York Times',
  description: 'The club, one of the world’s richest teams, had faced a two-year exile from Europe’s top soccer competition for breaking cost-control rules. It had long denied wrongdoing.',
  url: 'https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/13/sports/soccer/manchester-city-champions-league.html',
  urlToImage: 'https://static01.nyt.com/images/2020/07/13/sports/13mancity-trophy/13mancity-trophy-facebookJumbo.jpg',
  publishedAt: '2020-07-13T08:51:00Z',
  content: 'Still, the rules had not stopped City from winning everything but the Champions League title, the crown its owners covet the most. It has another chance to win it in August, when the Champions League… [+1751 chars]'
}
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with exaample data. If the API works, just post a short example from the data returned

Comment: There is no `articles` key in your JSON response

Comment: @kenny the full json response wouldve been too lengthgy to post, the response shown is the first item in the articles array.

Comment: You do change `API_KEY` to YOUR API key which you requested and paid for, right?

Comment: yes, yes i do, if i didnt i wouldn't get a response. but normally my code is supposed to work right? like its not because of syntax or anything?

Comment: It is because your code cannot actually run in a browser - the newsAPI v2 is supposed to run on a server. If you make a NODE.js server process, you can proxy for your client and not reveal the API Key

Comment: Anyway, you need `let sports = document.querySelector(".sport")` and then later `sports.innerHTML = val;`

Comment: already tried that it still doesn't work

Comment: You forgot to tell us you were using node and not client side processing. [More examples on how to resturn data](https://www.google.com/search?q=node+return+response+api+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning variable, You are not appending data into the DOM.

Replace

```
sports = val;
```

With

```
document.querySelector(".sport").innerHTML = val;
```

Comment: i just tried this it still doesnt work

Comment: Just put `console.log(document.querySelector(".sport")` before this line and check what output you get in console. And share it here. Also just check for any other errors

Comment: the only error shown in the chrome console is ReferenceError: require is not defined. apart from that console.logging sport returns undefined.

Answer (score 0):

IF the api had a CORS version then you could do this

```js
const res = { "status": "ok", "totalResults": 10, "articles": [ { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "Coronavirus: Llamas provide key to immune therapy", "description": "Llamas' specially evolved small antibodies are the basis for a coronavirus treatment breakthrough.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/science-environment-53369103", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/EE07/production/_113353906_llamas.jpg", "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T11:20:20Z", "content": "Image copyrightUniversity of ReadingImage caption\r\n Llamas and alpacas have evolved antibodies that scientists 're-engineer' in the lab\r\nAs Fifi the llama munches on grass on a pasture in Reading, he… [+2831 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "China slaps sanctions on Rubio and Cruz", "description": "The move comes after the US sanctions Chinese officials for Beijing's actions in Xinjiang.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-china-53387331", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/41C3/production/_113353861_rubio-cruz.jpg", "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T10:59:52Z", "content": "Image copyrightReuters / GettyImage caption\r\n Marco Rubio and Ted Cruz are prominent figures in the US Republican party\r\nChina has announced sanctions on top Republicans after the US imposed sanction… [+3122 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC Sport", "title": "Manchester City overturn two-year ban from European competition on appeal to Cas", "description": "Manchester City successfully overturn their two-year ban from European club competitions.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/football/53387306", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/onesport/cps/624/cpsprodpb/13590/production/_97584297_breaking_news.png", "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T08:45:57Z", "content": "Manchester City have successfully overturned their two-year ban from European club competitions.\r\nThe Court of Arbitration for Sport (Cas) announced the club were cleared of \"disguising equity funds … [+702 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "Nelson Mandela's daughter Zindzi dies", "description": "The youngest daughter of South Africa's first black president dies aged 59.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-53387667", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/12CD7/production/_113351077_gettyimages-465640143-002.jpg", "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T07:27:35Z", "content": "Image copyrightGetty Images\r\nZindzi Mandela, the daughter of South Africa's anti-apartheid icons Nelson Mandela and Winnie Madikizela-Mandela, has died, public broadcaster SABC has reported.\r\nShe die… [+518 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "Actress Kelly Preston, John Travolta's wife, dies", "description": "The US actress after a \"two-year battle with breast cancer\", Travolta said.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-53387236", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/11431/production/_113350707_mediaitem113350706.jpg", "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T06:25:14Z", "content": "Image copyrightAFPImage caption\r\n Travolta and Preston were married for more than 20 years\r\nKelly Preston, actress and wife of John Travolta, has died aged 57.\r\nTravolta posted on Instagram to say Pr… [+1073 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "Coronavirus updates: Global record for daily virus cases, says WHO", "description": "More than 230,000 cases were confirmed on Sunday - mostly in the Americas and South East Asia.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/live/world-53386093", "urlToImage": "https://m.files.bbci.co.uk/modules/bbc-morph-news-waf-page-meta/4.1.3/bbc_news_logo.png", "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T04:22:22.9453632Z", "content": "Amitabh Bachchan, 77, has starred in hundreds of filmsImage caption: Amitabh Bachchan, 77, has starred in hundreds of films\r\nIndian megastars don't come bigger than the Bachchans, a family considered… [+1062 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "US federal execution set to go ahead after 17 years", "description": "The execution of convicted murderer Daniel Lewis Lee had been blocked on Friday by a federal judge.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-53385642", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/170BA/production/_113349349_mediaitem113349348.jpg", "publishedAt": "2020-07-13T00:44:48Z", "content": "Image copyrightAFPImage caption\r\n Lee killed a family of three before dumping their bodies in a lake\r\nThe first federal execution in the United States for more than 17 years is set to go ahead in Ind… [+2178 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "Working from home burnout", "description": "A personal trainer, an advertising agency worker and a musician share their experiences of burnout.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-53352234", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/E467/production/_113317485_p08kbdvh.jpg", "publishedAt": "2020-07-12T23:02:58Z", "content": null }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "Duda ahead by tiny margin in Polish election - exit poll", "description": "Conservative President Andrzej Duda leads by a tiny margin against Warsaw mayor, exit poll suggests.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-53385021", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/148B2/production/_111764148_breaking-promo.png", "publishedAt": "2020-07-12T19:16:56Z", "content": "Poland's conservative president Andrzej Duda leads by tiny margin in run-off against Warsaw mayor, exit poll suggests.\r\nThis breaking news story is being updated and more details will be published sh… [+203 chars]" }, { "source": { "id": "bbc-news", "name": "BBC News" }, "author": "BBC News", "title": "Florida breaks record for daily coronavirus infections", "description": "A 24-hour tally of 15,299 new cases eclipses the worst daily rates seen in New York in April.", "url": "http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-53382540", "urlToImage": "https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/1024/branded_news/5DA6/production/_113347932_mediaitem113347931.jpg", "publishedAt": "2020-07-12T19:05:16Z", "content": "Image copyrightEPAImage caption\r\n Intensive care units at many Florida hospitals are reaching capacity\r\nFlorida has registered a state record of 15,299 new coronavirus cases in 24 hours - around a qu… [+1842 chars]" } ] };

document.querySelector(".sport").innerHTML = res.articles.map(
  art => `<h3 class="title">${art.title}</h3><p class="description">${art.description}</p><p class="author">${art.author}</p><hr/>`
).join("")
```

```html
<div class="sports section">
  <h1>SPORTS</h1>
  <div class="sport"></div>
</div>
```

NOTE that code ONLY works if the API allows your to access it from JAVASCRIPT, and it does not look like it does

https://newsapi.org/docs/client-libraries

We have libraries for the following languages:

- Node.js
- Ruby
- Python
- PHP coming soon
- Java coming soon
- C#

So I recommend you simply use the node as an API proxy and do something like

```
const NewsAPI = require('newsapi');   
const newsapi = new NewsAPI('API_KEY');  
newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({ category: 'sports', language: 'en', country: 'us' })
.then(result => res.send(result)) 
.catch(rej=>{ console.log(rej); })
```

Alternatively look into EJS

Comment: my problem is it doesn't show up on the page at all, i want to at least get the first item of the array to be displayed before trying to loop through it.

Comment: Then there is something else going on. Console errors or such. CORS error for example

Comment: Also "require" is not JavaScript, you need to run that in React or NODE

Comment: You cannot access the newsAPI from a browser without a server proxy

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm still very confused because i don't understand how you make api calls then. and if it doesn't accept javascript why did i get a response. it's frustrating

Comment: Where did you run and get a response, perhaps I am wrong, but I did not see how you can call `const newsapi = new NewsAPI('API_KEY');` in a browser

Comment: i displayed the response in the question, i think newsapi = new NewsAPI('API_KEY'); just created an instance.

Comment: newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
category: 'sports',
language: 'en',
country: 'us'
})   this was the call, if you check the question you'll see the response

Comment: In the browser or in a node.js on the server?

Comment: i ran it in using node

Comment: That is a VERY IMPORTANT MISSING INFORMATION!!!

Comment: NODE does not have a document! EITHER you return the JSON to an html page with JavaScript that looks like mine above OR you have to insert the parsed JSON into the page just where the <P></P> is now OR use a framework that can access HTML like express

Comment: I recommend making a proxy and ajax the content. Like `const NewsAPI = require('newsapi');

 const newsapi = new NewsAPI('API_KEY');

newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
category: 'sports',
language: 'en',
country: 'us'
}).then(result => res.send(result))
.catch(rej=>{
console.log(rej);
})`

Comment: thats what i'm trying to dooooooo, i know node doesn't have a document object i'm just telling you i used the node "filename" command to actually check if i got a response from the api and i did. i've already tried your code my goalk is to put the json response in the html page

Comment: So see my latest update. just call the api on node and return the response. That way you can use simple fetch on the browser client

Answer (score -1):

```js
let sports = document.querySelector(".sport").innerHTML;

newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
category: 'sports',
language: 'en',
country: 'us'
}).then(res =>{
let val = res.articles[0];

sports = val;

})
```

What you are doing here is assigning a value of `innerHTML` to a variable `sports`, and that is not working as you might expect. `sports` only contains its value, but not reference, which means that changing the value of `sports` doesnt change the value of `innerHTML`.

What you can to do is to assign the sports element to variable `sports` and then assign the incoming API value to its `innerHTML`:

```js
let sports = document.querySelector(".sport");

newsapi.v2.topHeadlines({
category: 'sports',
language: 'en',
country: 'us'
}).then(res =>{
let val = res.articles[0];

sports.innerHTML = val;

})
```

Comment: i just tried this it doesn't work, any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't work'? What errors you got, if any? Try logging into console different part of the logic, start with `sports` element, check if its already loaded when the script starts.